# Set header as application/json Github Pages

Tags: github, https, github-pages, deep-linking, ios-universal-links

I have a simple html website on Github pages for which I want to include the apple-required file `apple-app-site-association` to verified my domain, such file has no extension, but the content type has to be `application/json`.

Here's what's inside the file:

```
{
   "webcredentials": {
      "apps": ["YOUR_TEAM_ID.BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER.app"]
   }
}
```

Here's the path:

`https://<<mydomain>>/.well-known/apple-app-site-association`

After validating the file I see:

[image]

Normally I would do this in nginx, but since the website is hosted using Github pages and has no proxy associated to it, how can I do this?

pd: I'm also using Cloudflare, I don't know if there is an option for this using this service.

Thank you

Comment: GitHub Pages doesn't offer this as a configurable option.  In fact, it provides no way to configure the HTTP server at all.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the clarification @bk2204

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do it with Cloudflare, however if someone knows how this can be done within Github, please add the answer.

Github Pages + Cloudflare solution

1. Go to Rules and add a new Response Header Modification
   [image]
2. This is how the rule looks:

[image]